# Typical L1 and L2 access latency for SoCs made of ARM Cortex-A9

Tags: arm, cpu-cache, tegra, omap

I am looking for L1 access latency and L2 access latency for SoCs made from ARM Cortex-A9 processors such as Nvidia Tegra 2 and Tegra 3 which have multiple ARM A9 processors.

I could find some information about the L1 and L2 size of those architectures, but I could not much information about the L1 and L2 access latency. The only reliable information I found is that "L2 cache latency is 2 cycles faster on Tegra 3 than 2, while L1 cache latencies haven't changed."

[Here](http://forum.canardpc.com/showpost.php?p=3295102&postcount=491) is mentioned that L2 on Tegra 2 has a latency of 25 cycles and [here](http://www.sisoftware.net/?d=qa&f=xolo) is mentioned that L1 has a latency of 4 cycles and L2 has a latency of 31 to 55 cycles. None of these references are fully reliable. I was hoping to find more info on Nvidia, TI, and Qualcomm websites and technical documents, but no success.

EDIT: information on similar SoCs like OMAP4460 and OMAP4470 would be great too.

Comment: May I ask why do you need this?

Comment: to do some cache performance comparison on SoCs that use ARM-A9 processors. The cache for A9 can be architected in different ways, so you'll end up systems with very different performance and energy consumption. I need to have these cache numbers so I could speculate A9 performance for some applications.

Comment: L1 is tightly coupled with A9, L2 is generally L2C-310. What do you mean by architected in different ways? They have a few settings for ram latencies or they can have different sizes. Cache latencies in general is not trivial. See the titles under here http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0246h/BABIECJB.html

Comment: I found some numbers on p. 28 [here](http://wenku.baidu.com/view/eae3f1fbfab069dc5022018b.htm) which compare UP vs MPCORE with and without L2C-310. That doc suggests L1 latency should be 1 cycle (I'm not sure); L2 numbers are marginally less than what you noted. But as auselen has noted, there are settings that affect L2.

Comment: Did you find these infos? I need to know these (i.e. clean/dirty L1/L2   access latency) for A9 MPCore. Any advice?

Comment: @JohnTortugo Not much more info apart from the info that you can find on the links in this post.

Answer (score 4):

For an authoritative answer, you can try running [**`lmbench`**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lmbench/) ([HowTo](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Lmbench)?) on the target of your choice.

A set of results for **AM37x** (variant of TI OMAP3 family) is available **[here](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/LMBench_on_ARM_Microprocessors#Memory_Latency)** for reference.

Also checkout [this presentation](http://www.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/integriertesysteme/emuco/files/System_Level_Benchmarking_Analysis_of_the_Cortex_A9_MPCore.pdf) that describes the latency and bandwidth of various caches configurations on an ARM Cortex A9 MP system.